# How can i place my videos on my own server and make URL of them using net-beans

Tags: java, android, url, netbeans, android-videoview

I want to store videos on my server and make URL of them so i can use in android video view.
e.g 
http://swytchboard.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/102_1378616771.mp4

Please help me how can i do this using java or using some other environment .